# jQuery Traversing .next() .show()

Tags: jquery

Having an issue with traversing in jQuery.. hopfully an easy one..but I'm banging my head. I've tried `.closest()`, `.next()`, `.find()`.. and nada

HTML:

```
<div class='news_box'>
    <img src='".NEWS.$n[image]."' alt='$n[title] Image' class='news_img' />
    <div class='news_text'>
        <h3>$n[title] // ".date("d.m.Y", strtotime($n[created_on]))." // ".date("H.i", strtotime($n[created_on]))."</h3>
        <p>".substr(strip_tags($n[description]), 0, 90)."... <span title='Read More On $n[title]' class='more'>Read More</span></p>
    </div>
    <p class='clear'></p>
    <div class='full_item'>
        $n[description]
    </div>
</div><!--close news_box-->
```

Jquery:

```
$(".news_box span.more").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".full_item").show();
});
```

CSS for `.full_item` is set to `display:none`
The aim is to show the div: full_item on click of the span `.more`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `console.log(this)` can be very helpful in seeing what is being grabbed compared to what you are expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.more` is inside a `p`, which is inside `.news_text`, and `.full_item` is a sibling of that. So the following should do the trick:

```
$(this).closest('.news_text').siblings('.full_item').show();
```

[.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: `next` will not work for his dom. it will not select an element

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that isn't playing ball either.

Comment: Good point, I removed the `.next()` and just kept the `.siblings()` answer

Answer (score 0):

span is not a sibling of .full_item. try

```
$(this).parent().nextAll(".full_item").show();
```

also, the function `next` **will not work**, because .full_item is not immediately following the parent of p. use `nextAll` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've put the solution into a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/55mUj/

```
$(".news_box span.more").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.news_text').siblings('.full_item').show();
});​
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(this).parent().next(".full_item").show();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".news_box span.more").click(function(){
   $(this).closest(".news_box").next(".full_item").show();
});
```

Should work.